# twitter typeahead 0.9.3 remote return URL and json object

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-typeahead

in bootstrap 2, I used the following code to post a json object,

```
$('#typeahead').typeahead({
        source: function (query, process) {
         var URL = 'http://localhost:8080/autocomplete/search/';
         var query = {"t:jsonStringField": {
                          "name": "model",
                          "value": "fusion"
                         },
                      "t:jsonStringFilter": [
                             {"name": "year","value": "2009"},
                             {"name": "make","value": "ford"}
                         ]
                      }; 

            return $.getJSON(URL,
                { query: JSON.stringify(query)},
                function (data) {
                    return process(data);
                });
        }
    });
```

Now in twitter tyeahead 0.9.3 they have done away with the source concept and moved to a remote concept, but unfortunately I do no know how to work with it.

```
$(".typeahead").typeahead({

     remote : {    
      url: 'http://localhost:8080/autocomplete/search/',

      replace: function(uri, query) {

         var query = {"t:jsonStringField": {
                          "name": "model",
                          "value": "fusion"
                         },
                      "t:jsonStringFilter": [
                             {"name": "year","value": "2009"},
                             {"name": "make","value": "ford"}
                         ]
                      }; 

         return uri + JSON.stringify(query);
      },

      filter: function(response) {
           return response.matches;
      }

      return process(resultList);

    }
 }
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work, how do I just post the JSON object rather than appending it to the string? Thanks.

Comment: Consider to use: https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead

Comment: This doesn't answer my current question, but I must inquire anyhow. Does this work just as the old one did and does it work well with bootstrap 3?

Comment: yes it will work with Bootstrap 3 and you can use your "old" calls / code

Comment: @BassJobsen So although I was able to get version 0.9.3 working using an urlEncoded json object, I actually switched to your bootstrap-3-typeahead fork. I wasn't happy with the lack of features provided by 0.9.3 such as auto selecting the first item and the ability to do programmatic searches. Thanks for the library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your original code you use $.getJSON. This will send a request (and expects json as result) to: `http://localhost:8080/autocomplete/search/?query=%7B%22t%3AjsonStringField%22%3A%7B%22name%22%3A%22model%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22fusion%22%7D%2C%22t%3AjsonStringFilter%22%3A%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22year%22%2C%22value%22%3A%222009%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22make%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22ford%22%7D%5D%7D`

To do the same for Twitter's Typeahead call your replace function of your remote data should return a valid url. In your function the `?query=` part of the url is missing.

You will have to set: url: `'http://localhost:8080/autocomplete/search/?query=',`

You also will have to urlencode you json input maybe.

Note: you will not need the line `return process(resultList);` You will have to use the filter function to convert your json results to valid data:

> The individual units that compose datasets are called datums. The
>   canonical form of a datum is an object with a value property and a
>   tokens property.

you could use templates to style your dropdown results, see: http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/

> By default, the dropdown menu created by typeahead.js is going to look
>   ugly and you'll want to style it to ensure it fits into the theme of
>   your web page.

You will need the additional CSS from https://github.com/jharding/typeahead.js-bootstrap.css to style the default dropdown for Bootstrap.